# how to iterate in a bson document in java

Tags: java, iteration, document, bson

I am trying to iterate through a bson document in java but I get an error

```
new Document().append("test",1).forEach(record -> {
        System.out.println(record);           ^ error here
});
```

I get:

> Error:(556, 49) java: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types
>   in lambda expression, expected parameter 2 but found 1

when I try to add another parameter everything broke

```
new Document().append("test",1).forEach(record, param2 -> {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the fact that [`Document`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/Document.html) implements the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html?is-external=true) interface, that means it also inherits the default [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method which takes a [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) as a parameter. Thus your lambda should be like this:

```
.forEach((key, value) -> { ... }
```

Comment: I will in 3 minutes ... it does not allow to do it now

Comment: Ah I see, no probs :)